# How to Find by object - is there functional similar to Hibernate's .createCriteria() in EF 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a lot of objects, each other with a lot of fields.

I used Hibernate `createCriteria()` functional in Java, that allows to find records in DB by passing initilized object with values in some fields, for example:

```
    Personne personne = new Persone() {field1="f1", field2=123}

    List<Personne> listPersonne;

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testhibernate0");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Example personneExample = Example.create(personne);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Personne.class).add(personneExample);

    listPersonne = criteria.list();

    entityManager.close();
```

Hibernate iterates through all fields of passed objects and constructs query based on field values of passed object. So, I don't need to code all fields of object in `where()` with Hibernate.

The main idea is to find data in DB by fields of object.
Yep, I could code with `.where()` all fields, but it will be too hard to code all of those fields in `.where()`

Is there a similar functional in Entity Framework 6.0?

Comment: Can you show the code in `Example.create(personne)`?

Comment: It's Hibernate functional, for creating Criteteria Example. Just ignore this line of code and imagine, that `personne` has been passed as method argument and `personne` has, for example, 3 fields, filled with data of 5 possible fields of `Personne` object.

Answer (score 0):

EF has no need for such an API, because LINQ is just much better.  You can write a query directly in C# and EF will translate it to SQL and marshal the results into a collection.

Simply:

```
var q = db.Personne.Where( p => p.field1="f1" && p.field2=123 );
var results = q.ToList();
```

Comment: And what about, if there are about 50 fields should act in where clause? To code them in `where()`. It's not a good idea...

Comment: But you'd have to code them in the exemplar.  And it's very uncommon to use 50 fields in a where clause.